# Database relationship with internet connection

Tags: database, networking

So I am new to this and still have many question because I am not a good researcher on google

does internet connection on my client and database server effect
how fast I can insert or select or update my table in database?

and how does it affect my query?
does my bandwidth have a role in this tho?
and does specs also affect my speed to run a query and send it back to client side?

Current Backend : Go-Lang
Database : Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert will go trough server because PHP is server based.
if you run PHP intern and your internet is bad people will have a bad insert as well.

Comment: say that I use Go and oracle as my DB would internet connection still my limitation to get fast query?

like if I need to select query that return 500.000 row or insert thousands of row because I need batching and doing using corn job to do that

Comment: depends if you run intern or you host somewhere else.

Comment: well in this case , mine is hosted
and I need to use my database public IP to connect to it

Comment: this can take longer because you may got a bad host, i reccommend SSD hosting.